# how unittest serialization and db access

Tags: unit-testing

What is the correct way to write unittests for things like serialization/deserialization or writing and reading objects to/from a repository? Should I test if each and every property of my objects is correctly read and written? This seems like quite a lot of work when I have lots of types with lots of properties. Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For serialisation testing, you may want to serialise and compare vs. a canned test (i.e. a pre-serialised object that you know is correct).

So you would have to initially check that your canned serialised object is correct. From that point on, you're performing a regression test by simply comparing a byte stream / string or however your serialised object is represented. It may not tell you easily *what* has changed, but it will perform the primary function of a regression test and tell you *something* has changed.

Comment: Yeah. Version skew is probably the most likely bug to crop up when using serialization, and the "canned object" approach is a good way to test for this.